# pylint django with django-configurations

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, pylint

**UPDATE 2021 March 29** : There is a known issue [here](https://github.com/jazzband/django-configurations/issues/276)

**How to make pylint-django work together with django-configurations ?**

I've setup a Django project in VS code with pylint and django-pylint as linter.

I have a conflict with django-configurations, a package that I use to have different config file depending on environment.

I specify django-settings-module in order for django-pylint to understand django project.

Settings.json in vscode looks like this :

```
{
// ...
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--load-plugins", "pylint_django", // Works fine
    // "--django-settings-module", "project.settings" // Do not work anymore when adding this
    ],
],
// ...
}
```

Also I've tried the same config file with another django project that does not use django-configurations and pylint django works well with second line on.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make this work with this format:

```
{
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--load-plugins",
        "pylint_django",
        "--django-settings-module=project.settings"
    ]
}
```